# Having Trouble Accessing Function in Adjacent JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Currently in my directory I have App.js and startMenu.js as two separate files.
I would like to access startMenu.js in my App.js file with the correct React formatting.
Currently I can call the function startMenu() using typical javascript syntax, but I for some reason cannot get the React syntax {startMenu} to work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import startMenu from './startMenu';
import credits from "./credits";

var param = 'start';

class App extends React.Component {
  renderSwitch(param) {

    switch(param) {
      case 'credits':
        return credits();
      default:
        /*LINE IN QUESTION */ 
        return startMenu();
    }
    
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderSwitch(param)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks!

Comment: In case `startMenu.js` exports a functional component as default, you need to use `import StartMenu from './startMenu';` and now you can use `return <StartMenu />;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is depending how you are exporting your function.

If is doing this:

```
export default startMenu;
```

Then you might import that way:

```
import myFunction from './path';
```

That way the name does it care. You can call your function with any name when you are exporting by default.

---

But if you are exporting that way:

```
export { startMenu };
```

or

```
export startMenu;
```

So than you need import your function by your reall name, and if you are exporting just using `export` word, all members will be inside an object.

So you need do that:

```
import MyFunctions from './path';
```

or doing a import destruction

```
import { startMenu } from './path';
```

Comment: I am already using export default startMenu in my startMenu.js. From what you suggest, using {startMenu} should work already. Unfortunately, it does not. However, I am understanding that using this syntax is almost a nonissue though. Is there any detriment to using startMenu() as opposed to {startMenu} that you know of? I assumed the latter was normal React.js syntax

Comment: If you are exporting by default, you can not import using braces. This, `import { startMenu } from './startMenu'`, just will work if you are exporting without default. I do not see with good eyes an execution of a function in your import statement, so that, this, `startMenu()` in import statements, is wrong for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to properly export that function:

```
export function startMenu(...) { ... }
```

Then import it:

```
import { startMenu } from './startMenu';
```

If that's the only thing exported you can always `export default` and it simplifies the import.

You can only import things that have been exported. Everything else is considered private and is off-limits.

Answer (score 0):

The JSX syntax: `{foo}` means "Put this data here".

It *doesn't* mean "Call this variable as a function".

If you want to call it, you need to do so explicitly: `{foo()}`.